# Installing Ubuntu with Windows 8 on a separate partition

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I used a lIVE CD to install ubuntu and I selected the option install with windows 8. But I wanted the root to be mounted on a separate partition which I have created. How do I do this ?

When I say install along with ubuntu, where is the partition created and how do I resize this?

Answer (score 0):

Use GParted (available on the Live CD) to resize the partition, and when running the installer, at the partitioning screen, click "Edit" and use `/` as the mount point.